# How to bind a web site to a dynamic dns service?

Tags: iis-7.5, website, dynamic-ip, dynamic-dns

Since our ISP doesn't provide static IP, I am using a dynamic dns service to access a Windows server from the internet,

now I would like to expose a static web page to the net using a domain name that I just registered (ie: mydomain.tld not mydomaine.dynprovider.tld)

In IIS 7 -> Web site -> binding, I tried to set dynamic host instead of IP but found that this was not possible.

So, I wonder how to make binding for this web site, in order to make it pointing to the host dynamic IP.

Comment: Have you changed the DNS settings of the web hostname to that of the DNS ones?

Comment: I have not installed any DNS role on the server, and Dynamic DNS provider have the right settings which enable me to access the server remotely.

Comment: Are you binding the public ip address directly to the server NIC? This would be a whole lot easier if you bind an RFC 1918 ip address to the server and let your network firewall/router port forward from the public ip address to the private ip address.

Comment: @joeqwerty, glad to see you, my server is behind a shared connection (firewall/router), port forwarding is active and private ip address is fixed.

Comment: OK, so then you don't need to bind the web site to anything other than the private ip address on the server. The router/firewall will forward port 80 from the public ip address to the private ip address on the server. What it sounds like you want to do is to make sure that your public DNS correctly resolves to the public ip address. To do that you would install and configure a dynamic DNS client on the server so that the server can detect the public ip address and update the DNS record at your dynamic DNS provider.

Comment: So, In addition to the firewall DDNS configuration I need to have a dynamic DNS client on the server ? and set in the DDNS client the web site domain name that id exposed on my server ? right ?

Comment: I could run the DDNS client on server as service behind DDNS router settings, but with this client could not find where to manage domains.

Comment: If your router/firewall supports DDNS then you don't need anything on the server. I'm a little confused at this point. Can you explain in detail what you're trying to do on the server? The web site on the server should be bound to the private ip address of the server. You don't need to do anything else. The server doesn't know and doesn't care about the public ip address. Port forwarding from the public ip address to the private ip address is handled by the router/firewall.

Comment: I understand that any web site on the server should be bound to the server fixed private IP address, but in this case how does dns should work for these domain names, 
where are managed the dns records for these domains?  at the registrar level or at the dynamic dns provider level?
should I use Registrar name servers or Dynamic dns service provider name servers ?

Comment: In order to use a dynamic DNS client to keep your public DNS records updated you need to use a dynamic DNS provider. If your current DNS provider doesn't offer dynamic DNS then you need to move your DNS to a provider that does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important part of the answer to this question was given by @joeqwerty above, I only continued the research since he could not imagine all the scenario.

Since I found that generally Dynamic DNS providers give 1 to 3 host names (host.dynamicdnsprovider.tld type) free for 30 days, then one have to buy 1 service per domaine (mydomain.tld type) each one 2x to 3x more expensive than a static IP, at this time DNS for each domain could be managed into dynamic DNS provider control panel, so I returned to my registrar which provides dynamic DNS service for each registered domain but do not support or have any Client updater, then I searched for third party client updaters on the net and finally found one shareware which can support my registrar dyn services, run in background as windows service, and point multiple domains to the dynamic IP.
That way I can manage DNS records at my registrar, and use its name servers.

Now this is the second day updating, yesterday the server restarted after a Windows update, and DNS client updater restarted automatically.